# How did Archimedes calculate rational bounds of pi from a 96-gon?

Tags: geometry

Archimedes famously determined that $223/71 < \pi < 22/7$ using the 96-gons circumscribed by and circumscribing a circle of unit diameter. But I haven't found a reference that explains the final step, making the rational approximation. For example, the exact perimeter of the circumscribed 96-gon is:

$$ 48\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}} $$

How did Archimedes come up with 223/71 from that?

Comment: http://itech.fgcu.edu/faculty/clindsey/mhf4404/archimedes/archimedes.html

Comment: @selfawareuser, thank you for the link. Deleted my earlier comment since it had nothing to do with reality. Makes sence that Archimedes never actually used square roots, just invented an algorithm for approximating perimeters of $2n6$-gons

Comment: The joy of having a question answered by an anonymous link, now rotted, by an account that's now deleted... :-/

Comment: Here's an archived version of that page https://web.archive.org/web/20190101123108/https://itech.fgcu.edu/faculty/clindsey/mhf4404/archimedes/archimedes.html